# Assigning roles programmatically in grails using acegi

Tags: grails, spring-security

could someone provide me with a snippet that assigns a given existing acegi role (Authority) to a Person in Grails ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this to add a role to a user:

```
def role = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER")
def user = User.findByUSername("bob")
userRole.addToPeople(user)
```

To delete a role from a user:

```
userRole.removeFromPeople(user)
```

Plus to delete a user you need to remove the user from all roles first:

```
Role.findAll().each { it.removeFromPeople(user) }
user.delete()
```